# Was Douglas Crockford wrong with Strict Mode Example?

Tags: javascript, strict

I'm sure he wasn't. I just don't understand one example from his presentation

http://youtu.be/UTEqr0IlFKY?t=44m

```
function in_strict_mode() {
    return (function () {
        return !this;
    }());
}
```

Isn't it the same like this one?

```
function in_strict_mode() {
    return !this;
}
```

If `is_strict_mode()` would me `method` then I agree because `this` then would point to object containing method, for example

```
my_object.in_strict_mode = function() {
    return (function () {
        return !this;
    }());
}
```

But why he did it in his example (which is simple function, not a method of an object)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function in_strict_mode() {
    return !this;
}
```

This function can return different results *depending on how you call it*. Remember that the `this` context is determined by the function *call*, not the function *definition*. Therefore:

```
in_strict_mode.call(new Object()) === false
```

Crockford's version defines and immediately calls an inner function, so it can control the `this` context inside the call to the inner function. Therefore, his `in_strict_mode` cannot be tricked to return something else by `.call`ing it with a different `this` context.

Answer (score 7):

The value of `this` depends on how a function is called. The ("anonymous" in Crockford's code but "only" in yours) function determines if strict mode is on by looking at the value of `this` and requires that the function be called without explicit context for that to work.

It doesn't matter how you call Crockford's `in_strict_mode` function because it uses a different function to actually get the data it cares about.

It does matter how you call your `in_strict_mode` function, because it uses itself to get the data.

The Crockford version is designed to give the correct result even if you use it as a method on an object or call it using `apply(something)` or `call(something)`.

Answer (score 2):

The function shown will work both ways... i.e. you can put it in a "namespace" and still will tell you if you're in strict mode or not.

The simplified version `return !this` won't return the correct result if placed in a namespace and invoked with `mylib.in_strict_mode()`.